# jqplot chart displaying as red color fully in IE8?

Tags: jqplot

jqplot charts are showing red screen only in IE8, even their websites also showing the same. Is any fix available for this?

[jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php)

[image]

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a fix for this? I am getting the same error, but only on some installations of IE8 (it works in the MS IE8 virtualbox downloads okay) - I don't know what the difference is between them unfortunately. I've read some fixes that involve adding excanvas.js or changing `X-UA-Compatible` to `IE=8` but neither worked for me.

Comment: Hi @AndyBeverley I had tried little to fix, and i had removed the red color.

Comment: Thanks @pandiyan - what did you do to remove the red color?

Comment: I have edit color in CSS @AndyBeverley

Comment: Thanks. I found the "red" in the excanvas.js that's bundled with jqplot, but it's not present in newer versions. Upgrading seems to fix the problem - see answer below.

Comment: @AndyBeverley that's make sense

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to upgrade to the latest version of ExplorerCanvas (the one that's bundled with jqplot is an older version), and I also had to set the rendering mode to IE7:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

The older version of ExplorerCanvas uses red as a background color for the overlay, whereas the newer version does not.